# Provider to Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

So I am using the Flutter game template, which I found this:

```
 ProxyProvider2<SettingsController, ValueNotifier<AppLifecycleState>,
              AudioController>(
            // Ensures that the AudioController is created on startup,
            // and not "only when it's needed", as is default behavior.
            // This way, music starts immediately.
            lazy: false,
            create: (context) => AudioController()..initialize(),
            update: (context, settings, lifecycleNotifier, audio) {
              if (audio == null) throw ArgumentError.notNull();
              audio.attachSettings(settings);
              audio.attachLifecycleNotifier(lifecycleNotifier);
              return audio;
            },
            dispose: (context, audio) => audio.dispose(),
          ),
```

But unfortunately, I don't like provider. How to convert this provider to riverpod?

Comment: Hello Mosh. Did you get this working eventually? I'm folloing the same architecture and I have hit a snag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent in Riverpod would be:

```dart
final settingsProvider = Provider<SettingsController>(...);
final appLifecycleStateProvider = Provider<ValueNotifier<AppLifecycleState>>(...);


final audioControllerProivder = Provider<AudioController>((ref) {
  final audio = AudioController()..initialize();
  ref.onDispose(audio.dispose);

  ref.listen<SettingsController>(settingsProvider, (prev, next) {
    audio.attachSettings(next);
  });
  ref.listen<ValueNotifier<AppLifecycleState>>(appLifecycleStateProvider, (prev, next) {
    audio.attachLifecycleNotifier(next);
  });

  return audio;
});
```

Although it's possible that there are ways to simplify this further by using `ref.watch`. But the snippet above should be a good start

Comment: I will try this one

Comment: By the way, the ValueNotifier<AppLifecycleState> it seems a inherited widget
  `return InheritedProvider<ValueNotifier<AppLifecycleState>>.value(
      value: lifecycleListenable,
      child: widget.child,
    );`

Comment: how can I listen to the ValueNotifier<Applifecycle> inherited widget in my riverpod?

Comment: You can convert that provider into a riverpod's provider

Answer (score 0):

[Remi Rousselet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73894595/14829403)

Using the ref.listen is not working, What I did was change it into ref.watch

Comment: That's not the same thing as what you described in your question. Using `ref.watch`, your state will reset when the dependency changes